# Running a Windows Powershell script on instance launch with Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple Windows Powershell script I would like to have run on an EC2 instance when it launches within an Elastic Beanstalk environment. It simply sets up a self-signed SSL certificate and binds it to the default web site in IIS.

I know this can be done with an EC2 instance individually by using UserData (as shown below)... but how do I do it with any instance spun up inside an EB environment?

```
<powershell>
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-Location IIS:\SslBindings
New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https
$c = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "domain.com" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
$c | New-Item 0.0.0.0!443
</powershell>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Powershell expert but have you considered something like:

- Create a folder called .ebextensions inside your source bundle
- Create a file with any name but it should have .config extension
  (e.g. my script.config) and deploy it.
- The content of myscript.confi should have two keys i.e. Files and
  Commands. Be careful with Yaml formatting here which might be off and
  might cause the deployment to fail

> ```
>   files:  
>         "c:/targetdirectory/my_script.ps1":
>            content: |
>        <powershell>
>        Import-Module WebAdministration
>        Set-Location IIS:\SslBindings
>        New-WebBinding -Name "Default Web Site" -IP "*" -Port 443 -Protocol https
>        $c = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "domain.com" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My
>        $c | New-Item 0.0.0.0!443
>        </powershell> 
>            encoding: (encoding format either plain or base64)
>   commands:
>         run_my_script: 
>               command: ./my_script.ps1
>               cwd: "c:/targetdirectory/"
> ```

So basically, you're just creating a file that contains the script and then running it. [More info is here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html).

Comment: I read how EB doesn't care if the cert is self-signed, but does it look at the domain? My setup prevents me from knowing the environment's domain ahead of time, so wondering if putting something generic like domain.com in your example would work?